# Morphia for Mongo DB, and low performance code

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm copying a Mongo DB collection from a database to another, using Morphia in that way:

```
List<User> users = datastoreSource.find(User.class).asList();
datastoreDest.save(users);
```

This code works, however it takes hours to perform. I have a collection with 3 million documents in it and I would expect to copy it in few minutes. Can someone help me to improve that code?

Comment: You can "read" the link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/ and beware of the warnings there.

Comment: 3 million documents with a lot of information is normal to take quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm amazed this is working at all with 3 million documents. First you are loading them all into memory and then you are writing them back.

I would try reading a batch of data (say 100) with `.order("_id").limit(100).skip(i*100)` and [bulk write it back](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/329b2ea463d6ceba1be3ad74ddae652e20c49bf7/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/callbacks/TestPostPersist.java#L18).

And it would be interesting:

- How much data is that actually?
- How much memory do you have available? Do you start swapping?
- How much is "hours"? In the area of two or ten?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Kenster I totally disagree.